# Android daily notification even after cancel

Tags: android, alarmmanager

We are developing an application that should trigger an alarm intent notification start at 8AM everyday and repeat for every 15 mins once

In the notification, we are having button called "EOD", clicking on this should cancel the alarm and should not trigger any more for that day. But again next day morning it should start at 8AM.

The issue is after click on "EOD", we are calling cancel(intent) to cancel the alarm. But the alarm is not triggering for the next day. How to again trigger the alarm at next day 8AM ?

Comment: May be when you click on cancel button, after cancelling the alarm, you can re-create the intent so that it works for next day

Comment: While recreating the intent, do we need to use same requestcode or should i use different request code?

Comment: I think same should work

Comment: what is the flag i have to use in this case? I tried with FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT but it seems to be working fine. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

After you cancel the repetitive notifications using the intent.
Create another intent and send it ot alarm manager to start at next day 8am.

Comment: What about requestcode in pendingIntent..can i use same 0 as pending intent......  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationAlarmReceiver.class);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Comment: Request code must be different for each alarm you create

Comment: I have created another intent with different requestcode when click on "EOD" , its triggering alarm next day 8AM but the problem is again when click on "EOD" for the next day, its not cancelling because its with different request code.